# Good, working example of Angular2 with Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I've never used Electron and I'm attempting to find a good working example on github that uses Angular2 with electron that I can just download as a zip, and npm install, npm run watch, npm run electron (boom, working, queue applause). However, I can't find anything since this is such a new set of tools. Anything that I've found seems to no longer work despite being only a couple months old, such as https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-electron (various angular2 with ts issues). I'm not looking for someone to do my work, just a good template to get me started so I can poke around with the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code for that repository has been updated. Not the README file though :-(. In any case please download that repository again with the latest version and try the commmands again. I just tried them a few seconds ago and everything worked. I also followed his guide at: http://tphangout.com/angular-2-desktop-apps-with-electron/ and I was able to understand where everything is coming from. I highly recommend you to follow his guide and do it yourself.

Note: In the guide I mentioned above you are going to get an error just replace the main.js file you created when following the guide with the one from the repository.

Happy Angular2 + Electron!